# How to insert an image in DHTMLx Touch

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, mobile-application, dhtmlx

I'm using the [DHTMLx Touch online editor](http://dhtmlx.com/touch/designer/)

I have a layout with 3 cells

```
{ id: 'app', view: 'layout', height: 482, width: 322,
rows: [ { view: 'layout'
   , type: 'wide'
   , rows: [ { view: 'view', id: 'temp_designer_view_2'}
           , { view: 'view', id: 'temp_designer_view_3'}
           , { view: 'view', id: 'temp_designer_view_4'} ]
   , id: 'layout_2'} ] }
```

I want to place an image in the first cell with id 'temp_designer_view_2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to use "template" view to include HTML content into a layout item:

```
   { id: 'app', view: 'layout', height: 482, width: 322,
    rows: [ { view: 'layout'
       , type: 'wide'
       , rows: [ { template: "<div class='imgParent'><img .../></div>", id: 'temp_designer_view_2'}
               , { template: '', id: 'temp_designer_view_3'}
               , { template: '', id: 'temp_designer_view_4'} ]
       , id: 'layout_2'} ] }
```

Check the related samples in dhtmlxTouch package: ../samples/technical/view/04_template.html
and ../samples/technical/view/08_carousel.html